# poll for the right output of a command

Tags: bash, output, sleep

completely new to bash so any assistance is much appreciated. I'm looking for a script to do the following, its a pretty simple script but I cant seem to get it:

- I want to run a command, this command will return either **successful** or some other string in the output.
- if the output ***does not*** contain the word **successful** I want it to sleep for 5min and run again until it does contain **successful**.

It would look something like this

```
until (SOMECOMMAND) &> /dev/null
do
    if(SOMECOMMAND contains successful);
    break;
    else sleep 300
done

echo -e "\nThe command was successful."
```

Comment: `sleep 5` (in your code) would sleep for 5 *seconds* while the text says "sleep for 5 min" -- please edit your post and change one or the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

output=
count=0

until [[ $output =~ successful ]]; do
    output=$(somecommand 2>&1)
    ((count++))
    sleep 300
done

printf '\n%s\n' "Command completed successfully after $count attempts."
```

This will check if output *contains* successful, if you want to check that the output is **exactly** "successful" you can change the `=~` to `==`.

`$( ... )` is [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) which is being used to set the parameter `output` to the...output of `somecommand`.

Comment: Thank you this worked like a charm! just for my understanding why are we setting `output` to equal nothing?

Comment: Also what does the `2>&1` do?

Comment: @Minz: That redirects stderr to stdout, which is the same as `&>` that you have in your question but more portable.

Answer (score 2):

To run some-command until it outputs the string "successful" to stdout, sleeping five minutes after a failed run:

```
until some-command | grep -q successful
do
  sleep $((60 * 5)) ### or "sleep 5m", if supported by your version of sleep
done
```